# Get highest and lowest close price for a stock from dataframe creating user defined function

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

Get highest and lowest close price of a stock.

```
Parameters
----------
df: Pandas DataFrame containing data from Problem 1's solution
symbol: stock symbol

Returns
-------
returns two values, highest and lowest close price of the stock.
'''
```

I am trying to create a user defined function which will display max and min price for selected symbol.

I have the following code but it will only display the max and min for the close column from data frame. As per the lecture I am supposed to incorporate boolean mask but i am not sure how.

```
def get_high_low_close(df, symbol):
    symbol = df[df.stock == "AA"]
    highest_close = df['close'].max()
    lowest_close = df['close'].min()
return highest_close, lowest_close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want exactly, I'm guessing:

```
def get_high_low_close(df, symbol):
    mask = df['stock'] == symbol
    highest_close = df.loc[mask, 'close'].max()
    lowest_close = df.loc[mask, 'close'].min()
    return highest_close, lowest_close
```

See [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing).